# is it possible to make an search using algolia without using its ui?

Tags: reactjs, algolia

I want to do an algolia search using react instant search or instantsearch.js and want to store the result in an array instead of showing it using the ui , how can i do this ? I tried looking for the docs but there it is only mentioned to show the hits using the ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can call Algolia search and not use the UI components.

For example, you can use the package [algoliasearch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/algoliasearch) more information [here](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-javascript).

```js
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');

const client = algoliasearch('YourApplicationID', 'YourAdminAPIKey');
const index = client.initIndex('your_index_name');

index.search('Fo')
  .then(({ hits }) => {
    console.log(hits);
  });
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i was looking for , tysm bro